# A form that was changed from .Hide() to .Show() can't maximize,why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windowstate

I written a method that Hide or Show all forms of application(including forms children). The code is the following:

```
public enum FormState
{
    Show ,
    Hidden,
    Enable,
    Disable
}

private void SetAllFormsState(FormState formState)
{
    FormCollection forms = Application.OpenForms;
    FormWindowState formWinState;
    bool state;

    if (formState == FormState.Show)
    {
        formWinState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        state = true;
    }
    else if (formState == FormState.Hidden)
    {
        formWinState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        state = false;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("invalid flag");
    }

    for (int i = forms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Form form = forms[i];
        form.WindowState = formWinState;

        if (state)
        {
            form.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            form.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

but when I call again the form:

```
SetAllFormsState(FormState.Show);
```

only the parent form can selected. The children forms is displayed in window/taskbar but seems "locked" by windows, can't be maximized or change to normal style.
how I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `form.WindowState` *after* the `Show()` and `Hide()` method calls:

```
for (int i = forms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  Form form = forms[i];
  if (state)
  {
    form.Show();
  }
  else
  {
    form.Hide();
  }
  form.WindowState = formWinState;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe try that:

```
private void SetAllFormsState(FormState formState) 
{
    FormCollection forms = Application.OpenForms;
    FormWindowState formWinState;
    bool state;

    switch(formState)
    {
        case FormState.Show:
            formWinState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            state = true;
            break;

        case FormState.Hidden:
            formWinState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            state = false;
            break;

        default:
            throw new ArgumentNullException("invalid flag");
            break;
    }

    foreach(Form form in forms)
    {
        form.WindowState = formWinState;

        if (state)
            form.Show();
        else
            form.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: @abatishchev ok, i'll know it for next time.